# Razor @Html.ValidationMessageFor() not displaying "validation error message"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@Html.RequiredLabelFor(x => x.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { Name = "1.first_name", tabindex = "1" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
```

Is there a reason why when passing second parameter to @Html.TextBoxFor the field is being validated but "validation message" does not appear?

```
@Html.RequiredLabelFor(x => x.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
```

When using an overload that accepts only one argument (lambda expression) "validation message" is being displayed correctly.

In my understanding the actual property is not being recognized?

Backing property:

```
[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max length 100 characters")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
[Display(Name = "First name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The unobtrusive validation library identifies 'things to display validation for' using the name attribute. It's not that specifying extra properties stops it from working, but you have changed the name property and not reflected the new name in your validation helper.

You can either stop changing the name attribute in your textbox helper *(necessary if you use the default model binder to return your view)*, or you can use

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("1.first_name")
```

The above method is **not** a good idea ***unless*** you're using JS/JQuery to validate and submit your form data (via AJAX), for the reasons given by Stephen in comment to this answer.

Comment: Do not use `@Html.ValidationMessage("1.first_name")`. Not only does this mean that all model binding is lost when you post back, if the view is returned, the `ModelState` error will never be displayed for this property

Answer (score 6):

You have changed the `name` attribute, so not only will it not post back and bind to your model, jquery.validate.unobtrusive can now no longer match up the controls since the input has a different name than the associated validation message

```
<input name="1.first_name" ... />
<span .. data-valmsg-for="FirstName" ..></span> // There is no control named FirstName
```